# How can I instantiate and sync a LineRenderer in multiplayer network?

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer, synchronization, unity-networking

I am trying to make a laser that will be visible to all clients in a multiplayer networked game on Unity.

I've tried using a Command Attribute but that hasn't worked. I also found some ideas to use RpcClient but I am not quite sure how to implement that.

The code I'm using for the laser (I just run the method in Update) is:

```
public void CmdActivateLaser(bool laserState)
{
    if (laserState == false)
        return;


    pointer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);

    RaycastHit endCommand;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out endCommand))
    {

        finalPos = new Vector3(0f, 0f, endCommand.distance);
        pointer.SetPosition(1, finalPos);

    }
    else
    {
        pointer.SetPosition(1, transform.forward * 500f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `transform.forward * 500` is not necessarily a location that is 500 units in front of the object.  `transform.forward` is equal to `(0,0,1)` multiplied by a rotation matrix.  If you want a point that's *actually* 500 units in front of the transform, you need to *add the transform's position,* `transform.position + transform.forward*500`